# Browserfield not displaying in BlackBerry Curve 9360

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

In my BlackBerry application, I am using a `browserfield` to display a URL. This is working fine on the Bold 9700, and Bold 9900. But on the Curve 9360 it shows

> connection timed out: port 80

Working Scenario

```
Location: Bangalore, India
Network : 3G
Device : Bold 9700, Bold 9900
External Browser (Black berry inbuild Browser) : Working
In side APP ( Browser Field ) : Working
```

Not working Scenario

```
Location: Dubai, UAE
Network : 3G
Device : Curve 9360
External Browser (Black berry inbuild Browser) : Working
In side APP ( Browser Field ) : Not Working
```

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: which kind of network source you are using like wifi,BIS,BES etc?

Comment: Any reason you chose browserfield app over webworks? You may need to setup your connections as I believe the defaults aren't correct for every version of BBOS